# Relational Algebra Equivalence (basic)

Tags: relational-algebra

I'm just getting started on an intro to databases course and have a question about writing relational algebra expressions.

Schema:

```
Person ( name, age, gender )
Frequents ( name, pizzeria )
Eats ( name, pizza )
Serves ( pizzeria, pizza, price )
```

I have a practice question like such: Find all pizzerias that serve at least one pizza that Amy eats for less than $10.00.

**My answer is**: πpizzeria (σname = 'Amy' ^ price < $10 (Person ⨝ Serves))

**A correct answer is**: πpizzeria (σname = 'Amy' (Eats) ⨝ σprice < $10 (Serves))

I would like to know if these two are equivalent to each other, and if not, why not?